# Photoshop color difference

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I am having a very odd problem. I have a photo that I took with my Nikon d5000 uploaded to photoshop, without any adjustments other than a crop, and then when I export it the color changes drastically In this screenshot, you can see the photo in windows photo viewer on the left, and Photoshop on the right. Do any of you know why this is occurring?[image]

Comment: When I look at the original file from the camera it looks like the one in photoshop, not the exported version.

Comment: Is viewer aware of the profile?

Answer (score 2):

When you export, you do so for sharing via e-mail or on the Web. So, the format is most likely be JPEG. Make sure when you export it, or before exporting it, the color space is converted to sRGB. Photoshop, Lightroom, and other software are color space aware but not all viewing programs are. If you leave the photograph in its original color space, probably Adobe RGB or ProPhoto RGB, the viewing software may not be able to render the colors and tones properly.

Try opening the exported image back in Photoshop, I bet it will look right there. Now, to to Edit/Convert to Profile and read the current profile assigned to the image. If it is not sRGB, change it to sRGB and save it once more.

There are better software for viewing, may I recommend FastStone viewer from faststone.org. It is free and a very good viewer. It can be set to be color space aware but in some ways this may work against you. When you view a file with Adobe RGB FastStone will render it properly but at the receiving end, via e-mail or Web, the rendering software may not do justice to it. Use it carefully. I will not use the Windows viewer in any case, which seems to be in use in the image you shared.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I just used the default with Windows, so I will get FastStone for the future! I appreciate your help!